# What is summation for current group in rtf template?

Tags: obiee

I developed a oracle 10g BI Publisher report and having one issue. I am trying to sum value by current group but I am not getting correct results. Please help me.

```
<?sum(current-group()/DR[.!=''])?>
```

Ex: I have `<?sum(current-group()/DR[.!=''])?>` value is `19,234,770,654,698.34`. I had sum with calculator each amount in this group is not equal to above result. Manual summation result is `19,234,770,654,698.33`.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is quite late, but hope you will find this answer useful as It worked for me. Replace TAN_AMT with your column name and place that in the appropriate place.

```
<?sum(current-group()/TAX_AMT)?> - <?sum(current-group()/TOTAL_AMT)?>
```